# Ошибка при попытке получить путь к /data/app/ base.apk в C++

Tags: android, c++, jni

Я пишу защиту для своего приложения и я не могу никак получить путь к base.apk для того чтоб считать его md5 hash.

Вот код который у меня на данный момент и он при попытке загрузки приложение вылетает по причине: не найден ApplicationInfo:

```
const char *getBaseApkAbsolutePath(JNIEnv *env, jobject stop) {
    jclass native_class = env->GetObjectClass(stop);
    jmethodID pm_id = env->GetMethodID(native_class, "getPackageManager", "()Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;");
    jobject pm_obj = env->CallObjectMethod(stop, pm_id);
    jclass pm_clazz = env->GetObjectClass(pm_obj);
    jmethodID package_info_id = env->GetMethodID(pm_clazz, "getPackageInfo","(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/content/pm/PackageInfo;");
    jclass native_classs = env->GetObjectClass(stop);
    jmethodID mId = env->GetMethodID(native_classs, "getPackageName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring pkg_str = static_cast<jstring>(env->CallObjectMethod(stop, mId));
    jobject pi_obj = env->CallObjectMethod(pm_obj, package_info_id, pkg_str, 64);
    jclass pi_clazz = env->GetObjectClass(pi_obj);
    jmethodID getApplicationInfo = env->GetMethodID(pi_clazz, "applicationInfo", "()Landroid/content/pm/ApplicationInfo;");
    jobject jAppInfoObject = env->CallObjectMethod(pi_clazz, getApplicationInfo);
    jclass jAppInfoClass = env->FindClass("android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo");
    jfieldID jSourceDirField = env->GetFieldID(jAppInfoClass, "sourceDir", "Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring jSourceDirString = (jstring) env->GetObjectField(jAppInfoObject, jSourceDirField);
    const char *sourceApkPath = env->GetStringUTFChars(jSourceDirString, 0);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jSourceDirString, sourceApkPath);
    return sourceApkPath;
}
```

Comment: Вылетает куда? В Катманду? Разве не стоит приложить хотя бы минимум подробностей относительно того, что за ошибка и т.д.

Comment: `applicationInfo` не метод, а поле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я прочитав комментарии понял что ApplicationInfo Не загружается ибо я его вызвал не как поле.
Кому надо, код без ошибок ниже:

```
const char *getBaseApkAbsolutePath(JNIEnv *env, jobject stop) {
    const char* strGetApplicationInfo = "getApplicationInfo";
    const char* strContextClass = "android/content/Context";
    jclass _jcContext = env->FindClass(strContextClass);
    jmethodID _mGetApplicationInfo = env->GetMethodID(_jcContext, strGetApplicationInfo, "()Landroid/content/pm/ApplicationInfo;");;
    jobject result = env->CallObjectMethod(stop, _mGetApplicationInfo);
    const char* strSourceDir = "sourceDir";
    const char* strClass = "android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo";
    jclass _jcApplicationInfo = env->FindClass(strClass);
    jfieldID _fSourceDir = env->GetFieldID(_jcApplicationInfo, strSourceDir, "Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring reesult = (jstring)env->GetObjectField(result, _fSourceDir);
    const char* nativeString = env->GetStringUTFChars(reesult, 0);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(reesult, nativeString);
    return nativeString;
}
```